# Global and gauge charges

Tags: conservation-laws, charge, symmetry, gauge-theory, gauge-invariance

I have seen several questions regarding the difference between global and gauge charges, but I don't really get the physical implications.

The sQED lagrangian is:

$\mathcal{L}=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu \nu}^2 + |D_{\mu}\phi|^2-m^2 \phi^+\phi$

Which has a gauge symmetry:

$A^{\mu}\rightarrow A^{\mu}+ \partial^{\mu}\alpha(x)$

$\phi \rightarrow  e^{-i \alpha(x)} \phi $

But if we take $\alpha(x)$ the symmetry becomes global and then:

$A^{\mu}\rightarrow A^{\mu}$

$\phi \rightarrow  e^{-i \alpha} \phi $

Since we have a global symmetry we will have a conserved Noether current and a conserved charge. The same happens for QED, when we have a global $U(1)$ symmetry and therefore a Noether current. My question is:

When we have a gauge boson and a global symmetry (which comes from taking $\alpha(x)$ as a constant), is our conserved charge the electric charge? Moreover, if we hadn't the gauge boson in our theory, would the conserved charge be the number of particles?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/257018/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I have gone through all the links but did not find explicitly what I was looking for.