# Noether's first theorem and classical proof of electric charge conservation

Tags: electromagnetism, conservation-laws, charge, noethers-theorem, classical-electrodynamics

How to prove conservation of electric charge using [Noether's first theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) according to classical (non-quantum) mechanics? 
I know the proof based on using Klein–Gordon field, but that derivation use quantum mechanics particularly.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

By the word *classical* we will mean $\hbar=0$, and we will use the conventions of Ref. 1.

The Lagrangian density for Maxwell theory with various matter content is$^1$

$${\cal L} ~=~{\cal L}_{\rm Maxwell} + {\cal L}_{\rm matter} ,\tag{1}  $$

$${\cal L}_{\rm Maxwell}~=~ -\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu},\tag{2}$$

$$ {\cal L}_{\rm matter}~=~{\cal L}_{\rm matter}^{\rm QED}+{\cal L}_{\rm matter}^{\rm scalar QED} + \ldots,\tag{3} $$

$$ {\cal L}_{\rm matter}^{\rm QED}
~:=~ \overline{\Psi}( i\gamma^{\mu} D_{\mu}-m)\Psi ,\tag{4} $$

$$ {\cal L}_{\rm matter}^{\rm scalar QED}~:=~  -(D_{\mu}\phi)^{\dagger} D^{\mu}\phi -m^2\phi^{\dagger}\phi 
-\frac{\lambda}{4} (\phi^{\dagger}\phi)^2,\tag{5} $$

with covariant derivative

$$  D_{\mu}~=~d_{\mu}-ieA_{\mu}, \tag{6}  $$
and with Minkowski sign convention (-,+,+,+). (Here we are too lazy to denote various matter masses $m$ and charges $e$ differently.) The matter equations of motion (eom) are

$$ ( i\gamma^{\mu} D_{\mu}-m)\Psi ~\stackrel{m}{\approx}~0, \qquad 
D_{\mu}D^{\mu}\phi~\stackrel{m}{\approx}~m^2\phi+\frac{\lambda}{2} \phi^{\dagger}\phi^2, \qquad  \ldots.\tag{7}$$

(The $\stackrel{m}{\approx}$ symbol means equality modulo matter eom, i.e. an on-shell equality.)

The infinitesimal *global* off-shell gauge transformation is

$$ \delta A_{\mu} ~=~0, \qquad 
\delta\Psi~=~-i\epsilon \Psi, \qquad 
\delta\overline{\Psi}~=~i\epsilon \overline{\Psi}, $$
$$  \delta\phi~=~-i\epsilon \phi,\qquad 
\delta\phi^{\dagger}~=~i\epsilon \phi^{\dagger}, \qquad  \ldots,
\qquad\delta {\cal L} ~=~0,\tag{8} $$

where the infinitesimal parameter $\epsilon$ does *not* depend on $x$.

The Noether current is the electric $4$-current$^2$

$$  j^{\mu}~=~e\overline{\Psi}\gamma^{\mu}\Psi - ie\{\phi^{\dagger} D^{\mu}\phi-(D^{\mu}\phi)^{\dagger}\phi\}+\ldots. \tag{9}$$

[Noether's first Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noether%27s_theorem) is a theorem about *classical* field theory. It yields an on-shell [continuity equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_equation)$^3$

$$   d_{\mu}j^{\mu}~\stackrel{m}{\approx}~0.\tag{10}$$

Hence the electric charge

$$ Q~=~\int\! d^3x~ j^0\tag{11}$$

is conserved on-shell.

References:

1. M. Srednicki, *QFT.*

--

$^1$ Note that the matter Lagrangian density ${\cal L}_{\rm matter}$ may depend on the gauge field $A_{\mu}$

$^2$ Interestingly, the electric $4$-current $j^{\mu}$ depends on the gauge potential $A_{\mu}$ in case of scalar QED matter.

$^3$ Note that the above proof of the continuity equation (10) via Noether's first theorem (as OP requested) never uses Maxwell's equations.

Comment: I'm wondering if PhysiXxx would not prefer to call a "classical" proof a proof with real fields... then without gauge symmetry. I believe in "classical" Maxwell equations the conservation of charge $dQ / dt = 0$ is a postulate, leading to $\partial_{\mu} j^{\mu} = 0$ through integration over a finite volume.

Comment: It is true that [Maxwell eqs. $d_{\mu}F^{\mu\nu}\stackrel{A_{\lambda}}{\approx}-J^{\nu}$] $\Rightarrow$ [Continuity eq. $d_{\mu}J^{\mu}\stackrel{A_{\lambda}}{\approx}0$] $\Rightarrow$ [Electric charge conservation], where $J^{\mu}:=\frac{\delta S_{\rm matter}}{\delta A_{\mu}}$. In fact, here $J^{\mu}$ could be an unspecified background source that knows nothing about the matter theory. However, OP asked specifically to use Noether's first theorem in the proof. According to Noether's first theorem, we have [_global_ gauge symmetry of the action]$\Rightarrow$ [Electric charge conservation].

Comment: for the footnote 2: (Interestingly, the electric ....) This statement is weird. to my view, the on-shell 4-current $j^\mu$ is gauge-invariant and independent on the gauge potential $A_\mu$.  This part of scalar QED matter shows this result, $j^\mu \sim - ie\{\phi^{\dagger} D^{\mu}\phi-(D^{\mu}\phi)^{\dagger}\phi\}$

Comment: Hi @Zoe Rowa. Thanks for the feedback. As I see it $j^{\mu}$ is gauge-invariant but depends on $A$.

Comment: Hi @Qmechanic, thanks for your response. I agree your statement. Using the similar logic, one could say $F_{\mu\nu}$ is gauge-invariant and dependent on $A_\mu$.  For the terminology, *Gauge-invariant* is clear, while "dependence" is not clear enough, the latter needs more words to elucidate its content.

Comment: What are $\phi$ and $\Psi$?

Comment: They are matter fields.

Comment: @Qmechanic I guess I'm perhaps more familiar with them in a quantum than classical sense. I guess $\phi$ is a charged scalar field, similar to a charge distribution in space. But what is $\Psi$ classically? I guess it's a classical bispinor field?

Comment: Yes, and Grassmann-odd.