# Noether current and continuity equation in classical scalar QED

Tags: electromagnetism, conservation-laws, gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance

Consider the following scalar QED model
\begin{align}
S = \int \mathrm{d}^{d+1} x\,
\left\{-\left(\mathrm{D}_{\mu}\phi\right)^{\dagger}
\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi\right)
-m^2 \phi^{\dagger}\phi - \frac{1}{4} F_{\mu\nu} F^{\mu\nu}\right\}\,,
\end{align}
where $\eta_{\mu\nu} = \mathrm{diag}(-,+,+,+)$, and $\mathrm{D}_{\mu}\phi = \left(\partial_{\mu}-\mathrm{i} e A_{\mu}\right)\phi$.

Under the following infinitesimal gauge transformation
\begin{align}
\delta \phi = -\mathrm{i} e \Lambda(x)\,,\qquad
\delta \phi^{\dagger} = +\mathrm{i} e \Lambda(x)\,,\qquad
\delta A_{\mu} = -\partial_{\mu} \Lambda(x)\,,
\end{align}
the theory is expected to be invariant, leading to Noether identities, which obey continuity equations.

Under the infinitesimal gauge transformation above, calculation gives
\begin{align}
\delta S = \int\mathrm{d}^{d+1}x\,\bigg\{
&\mathrm{i} e \Lambda(x)
\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\mathrm{D}_{\mu}-m^2\right)\phi
- \mathrm{i} e \Lambda(x)
\left[\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\mathrm{D}_{\mu}-m^2\right)\phi\right]^{\dagger}
\\
&
-\partial_{\mu}\Lambda(x)\left[-
\mathrm{i} e \left(\phi^{\dagger}\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi-
\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi\right)^{\dagger}\phi\right)
+\partial_{\nu} F^{\nu\mu}\right]
\\
&
-\partial_{\mu}\left[ \mathrm{i} e \Lambda(x)
\left(\phi^{\dagger}\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi-
\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi\right)^{\dagger}\phi\right)
-\left(\partial_{\nu} \Lambda(x)\right)F^{\mu\nu}\right]\bigg\}\,,
\end{align}
where the first two lines would give equations of motion, and the third line might be related to a Noether current.

One sees that since $\Lambda(x)$ now is a space-time function, the derivation for Noether's first theorem does not immediately apply. How can I extract a Noether current, and how does the corresponding continuity equation look like? Do I have a conservation law here?

Edit 28.04.2019:

If I fix the transformation to be rigid $\Lambda(x) \equiv \Lambda$, I will get the current
\begin{align}
j^{\mu} = \mathrm{i} e \left(\phi^{\dagger}\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi-
\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi\right)^{\dagger}\phi\right).
\end{align}
Equipped with
\begin{align}
\partial_{\mu}\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi\right) &=
\left(\mathrm{i} e A_{\mu}\mathrm{D}^{\mu}
+m^2\right)\phi\,,
\\
\partial_{\mu}\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi\right)^{\dagger} &=
\left[\left(\mathrm{i} e A_{\mu}\mathrm{D}^{\mu}
+m^2\right)\phi\right]^{\dagger}\,,
\end{align}
which come from the equations of motion, one can derive
\begin{align}
\partial_{\mu}j^{\mu} = \mathrm{i} e \big\{&+
\left(\mathrm{D}_{\mu}\phi\right)^{\dagger}\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi\right)
+m^2\phi^{\dagger}\phi
\\ &-
\left(\mathrm{D}_{\mu}\phi\right)^{\dagger}\left(\mathrm{D}^{\mu}\phi\right)
-m^2\phi^{\dagger}\phi\big\} = 0.
\end{align}

Therefore,

1. From Noether's *first* theorem (*rigid* transformation), one does get a current, in the usual form.
2. The continuity equation contains $\partial_{\mu}$, instead $\mathrm{D}_{\mu}$. As a result, one does have a conserved charge. If it were $\mathrm{D}_{\mu} j^{\mu} = 0$, one would in general *not* have a conserved charge.

The question concerning what we can get from Noether's *second* theorem (*gauge* transformation) remains not answered.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/336793/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Please do not let [posts look like revision histories](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5886/50583). Markers such as "Edit:" are uncessary since everyone can access the history of a post if they are interested in what was added later.

Comment: Also related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/159273/50583

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you for the kind remark. I agree with the idea in that post. The thing is, I managed to answer a part of my original question. How should I make an update of the original post then?