# Electric Current in Classical Electrodynamics derived as Noether current

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-current, conservation-laws, charge, noethers-theorem

I'm looking for a derivation of the often quoted fact that
the conservation of electric(!) current $j^{\mu} = (c \rho, \vec{j})$ in
relativistic classical electrodynamics is an explicit consequence of
Noether theorem. In other words that that the
electric current $j^{\mu}$ is a Noether current with respect gauge transformation
$A_{\mu} \to A_{\mu} + \delta A_{\mu}= A_{\mu} + \partial_{\mu} \chi$ where
$\chi$ is any twice differentiable scalar function that depends on
position and time.

Recall from classical Electrodynamics $S = \int_V \mathcal{L} dV dt$ with
Lagrangian

$$\mathcal{L} := -\frac{1}{c} A_{\mu} j^{\mu} -\frac{1}{16 \pi}F^{\mu \nu}
F_{\mu \nu}$$

with field tensor $F_{\mu \nu} = \partial_{\mu} A_{\nu}-
\partial_{\nu} A_{\mu}$ and in context of variational calculus of
action functional $S$ the conserved function,
also called **Noether current** for action $\phi \to \phi + \delta \phi$
on Lagrangian $\mathcal{L}(\phi, \dot{\phi}, t)$ is defined by

$$J^{\mu} := \frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{\phi}}
\delta \phi$$

Now I not see why in context of relativistic classical electrodynamics
and gauge transformation of the $4$-potential $A_{\mu}$ (that is
$\phi := A_{\mu}$ and $\delta \phi = \partial_{\mu} \chi$ the obtained
Noether current $J^{\mu} $ coinsides exactly with
classical electric current $j^{\mu} = (c \rho, \vec{j})$?

Does anybody know where I can find a derivation of that?

My attempts:

By equation of motion and definition Maxwell-Lagrangian we have
$\frac{\partial F^{\mu \nu}
F_{\mu \nu}}{\partial \dot{A_{\mu}}}= -4 F^{\mu \nu}$, so
$\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{A_{\mu}}}= \frac{1}{4 \pi}F^{\mu \nu}$
and $\delta A_{\mu}= \partial_{\mu} \chi$. Why does it imply
$J^{\mu} = (c \rho, \vec{j})$. I not see it. Although I found in PSE some questions dealing which similar problem I nowhere found a source containing a full complete derivation of the claim, but on the other hand incountable many sources using this a fact.

Comment: Variation of the Lagrangian w.r.t. $A_\mu$ gives you the Ampere-Maxwell law featuring the current $j^\mu$. But the  $A_\mu$ gives you the Ampere-Maxwell law featuring the current $j^\mu$. But the  $A_\mu$ couples to the Noether current,   for gauge invariance, so to the same object. Where is the obscure part? You have barely defined several of your symbols, so your question does not read coherent.

Comment: Possible duplicate [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/112367/noethers-theorem-and-gauge-symmetry) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/159273/classical-em-clear-link-between-gauge-symmetry-and-charge-conservation/159463#159463).

Comment: @CosmasZachos: Is far I know the Ampere-Maxwell law relates up to constant
$\partial_{mu} F^{\mu \nu} = j^{\nu}$, combining the result above we 
have $\partial_{mu}\frac{\partial \mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{A_{\mu}}}=
j^{\nu}$, as far ok. The obscure part for me is where the variation 
$\delta \phi = \partial_{\mu} \chi$ occuring in Noether current apears
in electric current?

Comment: Which of my notations/symbols are not explaned well?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48305/2451 and links therein.

Comment: A: The fact that your expressions do not conserve indices μ across equality signs. You want to vary the lagrangian density with respect to $\phi_\mu$, not $\dot{\phi}$ !? is this a remnant of classical non covariant mechanics?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the Lagrangian for Electromagnetism is only gauge invariant for zero currents. With currents the Lagrangian is not invariant. The reason is that the gauge transformations actually changes the current since it comes from other fields like the spinor field in QED so that the transformation of the matter fields requires the Gauge field $A_\mu$ to mantain the general Lagrangian invariant, this transformation for that Lagrangian indeed gives the conservation of current.

Comment: It seems the OP would like to think of $j$ as being the coupling to the (dynamical) matter sector of the theory. In which case it might be worth pointing out that charge conservation is a constraint on how the matter fields are allowed to transform under a gauge transformation imposed to maintain gauge invariance.