# Local charge current for gauge field and conservation of charge

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, yang-mills, classical-field-theory

**Motivation:**

It is a well known fact that the gravitational field (in General Relativity and direct generalizations of it) has no local energy-momentum density.

Usually there are two reasons stated, one is heuristic, one is mathematical.

- *Heuristic reasoning:* The gravitational field can be "turned off" at any one $x\in M$ by a proper choice of reference frame, which implies there are problems defining a local density.
- *Mathematical reasoning:* The (Einstein-Hilbert) stress-energy (SEM) tensor of a matter field $\psi$ is defined as $$ T_{\mu\nu}=-\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S_m}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}} $$ where $S_m$ is the matter action. It is, in some sense, the response of the matter field action to changes in the metric. On the other hand, the response of the *gravitational action* to a change in the metric is $$ \frac{1}{16\pi G}G_{\mu\nu}=\frac{\delta S_{EH}}{\delta g^{\mu\nu}}, $$ which is basically the vacuum EoMs of GR, clearly this is not to be interpreted as a SEM tensor. *So the gravitational field has no SEM tensor.*

Moreover, the covariant conservation law $$ \nabla_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0 $$ is usually interpreted not as a genuine conservation law, but rather the exchange of energy-momentum between the matter field and the gravitational field.

**Background:**

Let $\psi$ be a matter field, whose target space carries a representation of a Lie group $G$, with action $$ S_m [\psi]=\int d^4x\ \mathcal L_m(\psi,\partial\psi)$$ such that the Lie group $G$ is a group of symmetries of $S_m$. From Noether's theorem, one may obtain $k$ (we have $h=\dim G$) conserved currents satisfying $$ \partial_\mu\mathcal J^\mu _a=0. $$

Let us turn the global symmetry into a gauge symmetry, introduce the gauge connection/gauge field $\mathcal A_\mu=A^a_\mu T_a$ ($T_a$ are a set of generators for $\mathfrak g$) through the covariant derivative $$ D_\mu\psi=\partial_\mu \psi + \mathcal A_\mu\psi, $$ and introduce a self-action $$ S_{GF}[A]=\int d^4 x\ \mathcal L_{GF}(A,F) $$ for the gauge field.

One may show the following:

- The current $$ j^\mu_a=\frac{\delta S_m}{\delta A^a_\mu} $$ is an equivalent current to the Noether current $\mathcal J^\mu _a$ *provided that $A\rightarrow 0$*. This includes the conservation law $\partial_\mu j^\mu_a=0$.
- With $A_\mu^a\neq 0$, the current satisfies the identity $$ D_\mu j^\mu_a=\partial_\mu j^\mu_a-A_\mu^cC_{c\ a}^{b}j^\mu_b=0, $$ where $ D_\mu $ is the covariant derivative in the coadjoint bundle.

**Question:**

The situation here is clearly analogous to the situation with GR but with $T^{\mu\nu}$ replaced with $j^\mu_a$. In particular:

- The conservation law $D_\mu j^\mu_a=0$ cannot be interpreted as a real conservation law, it expresses the fact that the matter field can exchange charge with the gauge field.
- It does not make sense to define a gauge current for the gauge field $A$, only for the matter field $\psi$.
- **Does that mean** that in a nonabelian gauge theory, the **local charge current density of the gauge field is ill-defined**?

If so, I would find it odd, since it is not something that's usually stated, plus unlike gravity, where you can "turn off" the "field strength" $\Gamma^\rho_{\mu\nu}$ by a choice of reference frame at a point, the gauge curvature $\mathcal F=d\mathcal A+\frac{1}{2}[\mathcal A,\mathcal A]$ cannot be eliminated at points via gauge transformations.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137061/2451

Comment: @Qmechanic I do not understand point 5) in your answer to the question you linked. In particular, it can be shown that the "full" current $j^\mu_a=\delta S_m/\delta A^a_\mu$ transforms under the coadjoint representation of $G$, so it is gauge-covariant, and it does satisfy a conservation law $D_\mu j^\mu_a$, albeit one with covariant derivatives instead of ordinary derivatives. Or do I misunderstand something?