# Can you quantize a field of charge density?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics

If I wanted to develop a model of quantum electrodynamics, but instead of an electron field, I quantized the scalar charge density field that is used in Maxwell's Equations, would it be possible? If so, how would this theory differ from quantum electrodynamics and classical electrodynamics?

Comment: As a quick disclaimer I do not *know* the answer nor claim to be an expert in any sense. But modelling the electron with a scalar field would lose it it's spin cf. Klein-Gordon field quantisation. There are also problems with coupling the scalar Klein-Gordon field to the electromagnetic field see [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/577723/what-prevents-two-quantum-fields-from-coupling) or [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251780/why-cant-a-real-scalar-couple-to-the-electromagnetic-field), which may also cause problems in your proposed theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In condensed matter physics charge oscillation waves are called [*plasmons*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plasmon), and quantizing them is not uncommon.

Quantizing continuum-like fields is a rather common procedure in condensed matter physics, resulting in a whole zoo of excitations: plasmons, phonons (lattice vibrations), magnons (quantized magnetic waves), and so on. AN easily accessible introduction is the Haken's ["Quantum field theory of solids"](https://books.google.fr/books/about/Quantum_Field_Theory_of_Solids.html?id=QGosAAAAYAAJ&redir_esc=y), while less worked through examples can be found in the Kittel's book.