# Charge conservation and $U(1)$-invariance

Tags: electromagnetism, charge, symmetry, conservation-laws, noethers-theorem

Let’s consider electromagnetic Lagrangian

$$\mathcal L=-{1\over 4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}\tag{1}$$

Is charge conservation derived as a consequence of $U(1)$-invariance of this Lagrangian?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/2721/2451 and links therein.

Comment: I vote to reopen because the question is specifically about gauge invariance as an explanation of charge conservation.

Comment: My answer: 

Charge conservation is related to the invariance of the Lagrangian under rotation in the complex plane, or, equivalently, under a complex phase shift, such as $$\phi \rightarrow \phi + i\delta \phi ~.$$

Often it is considered a consequence of electromagnetic gauge invariance. However, charge is also conserved in the absence of electromagnetism. It is therefore better to say that gauge invariant electromagnetism can only describe conserved charge.